# I am trying to install Lombok in my Ubuntu 22 version. It is for eclipse. When I am running command, it is giving permission denied

Tags: spring, spring-boot, eclipse, ubuntu, lombok

I am trying to install Lombok in my Ubuntu 22(latest version) for eclipse.
When I am running command

sudo java -jar lombok.jar

[Error shown in Lombok installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16PXF.png)

I am running above command by going into Downloads directory because my Lombok jar is there.
My eclipse location is this:-
eclipse.home.location=file:/snap/eclipse/61/

I have also tried going to snap/eclipse directory , moved the Lombok.jar file there with sudo su but that isn't also working.

When I tried this command in sudo su mode:-
cp -R /home/satya123/Downloads/lombok.jar /snap/eclipse/61/

It is giving this error:-

cp: cannot create regular file '/snap/eclipse/61/lombok.jar': Read-only file system

I tried this command so that my eclipse and lombok remains in same directory with root permission but this also not worked.

What should I do?

Comment: You can have your own eclipse.ini file in /home/satya123/snap/eclipse/current.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify a snap app, they are essentially containerized. You'll need a download from downloads.eclipse.org to be able to modify it with lombok.

Comment: That's a good idea, silly of me to not think about it..thanks..I will try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering in such a short span of time